Manual regression model with ARIMA(1, 0, 1) errors calculation in Excel
I am trying to replicate a regression model with ARIMA(1, 0, 1) errors in Excel, and I can't seem to match the results seen in R.
Lets assume I have a regression model with ARIMA(1, 0, 0) errors. This would be defined as:
$\hat{Y_t} = (\beta_1)*X_1+(\beta_2)*X_2+\hat{e_t}$
Where
$\hat{e_t} = (ar1)*e_{t-1}$
And
${e_t} = (ar1)*e_{t-1} + u$
I understand how to implement this, where the ar1 term here is just multiplied by the previous period's residual $(Y_{t-1} - \hat{Y}_{t-1})$
However, I can't seem to match the results when I add a moving average term to my ARIMA errors.
With ARIMA(1, 0, 1) errors, I believe the error formula is now:
$\hat{e_t} = (ar1)*e_{t-1}+ (ma1)*u_{t-1}$
Or
${e_t} = (ar1)*e_{t-1}+ (ma1)*u_{t-1} + u$
I need to calculate my $u$ based on the below:
$u = {e_t}-(ar1)*e_{t-1} -(ma1)*u_{t-1} $
But how do I get the first $u_{t-1}$ value?
I seem to be in an endless loop trying to figure this out. If there's a simple Excel example somewhere that someone can provide, that would be super helpful!
